# C# Hash SHA256Managed is not equal to TSQL SHA2_256

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, encoding, hash

I am using hashed passwords with a salt (the username).

Problem is that the hashed values of c# are not equal to the initial values I add to the database by a TSQL Script.

TSQL:

```
UPDATE [Users]
SET Password = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'test123'+UPPER([UserName]))
GO;
```

C#:

```
var passBytes = new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(pass);
var saltBytes = new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(userName.ToUpper());

var dataToHash = new byte[passBytes.Length + saltBytes.Length];
Array.Copy(passBytes, dataToHash, passBytes.Length);
Array.Copy(saltBytes, dataToHash, saltBytes.Length);

var sha = new SHA256Managed();
return sha.ComputeHash(dataToHash);
```

I guess it has something to do with the encoding.
But i have no idea how to fix this.

UserName is varchar(50)

**The DB is an existing one so changing the varchar will not be so easy.**

I already tried:

```
UPDATE [Users]
SET Password = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', N'test123'+UPPER([UserName]))
GO;
```

Comment: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2009/04/28/Comparing-SQL-Server-HASHBYTES-function-and-.Net-hashing.aspx

Comment: If the username your testing with  is only madeup of latin characters, it will be encoded with the same character codes as ascii and the result should therefore not be affected by the encoding.

Comment: You don't need to do `new UnicodeEncoding().Whatever()`, You can just do [`Encoding.Unicode.Whatever()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode.aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your SQL Server database is configured to use the default collation of SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, then in your C# code, use code page 1252 to convert characters to bytes. Thus, the equivalent of

```
HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'test123' + UPPER([UserName]))
```

is

```
byte[] data = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes("test123" + userName.ToUpper());
var sha = new SHA256Managed();
byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(data);
```

Answer (score 12):

After struggling to get this to work, here is a sample of what I finally got to work:

```
public string Hash(string input)
    {
        using (SHA256 hasher = SHA256.Create())
        {
            // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
            byte[] data = hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input));

            // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes
            // and create a string.
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            // Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
            // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("X2"));
            }

            // Return the hexadecimal string.
            return sBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

TSQL

```
declare @input as nvarchar(max) = 'Test';

select @input;

declare @hash as varbinary(max) = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @input );

select @hash;

declare @result as nvarchar(max) = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @hash, 2);

select @result;
```

These will produce identical results.

Note that this is using a nvarchar datatype, not a varchar.

Comment: Thanks! The `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` is crucial when you're using a `nvarchar` field!  The code page 1252 or UTF8 encoding will match the `varchar` field hashed.

Answer (score 5):

Hashes work on bytes, not on characters. What you're doing is `Hash(StringToBytes(str))`. Your `StringToBytes` step is different. In SQL you are using ANSI `varchar` strings and in C# UTF-16 strings. Decide which one you want and use that. I recommend Unicode (`nvarchar`).

Comment: The DB is an existing one so changing the varchar will not be so easy.
Could you give me an example of what i need to change?

Comment: Then change the C# app. Use an encoding that matches the varchar encoding. You probably have too search which one that might be.

Comment: You may want to look at [this article](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2009/04/28/Comparing-SQL-Server-HASHBYTES-function-and-.Net-hashing.aspx) it compares `varchar`, `nvarchar`, `char`, and `nchar` to the encoding `ASCII`, `UTF7`, `UTF8`, `Unicode`, and `UTF32`. It appears that `ASCII == varchar` if you even want to match the behavior of people passing in invalid text (`中文`) but for all English text `UTF8` will match `varchar` with the fastest results.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain a small addendum: ASCII is for chars <= 0x7F. Varchar can also use the first bit, so depending on the collation it can store other chars as well like öäüß. So the encoding depends on the collation.

Answer (score -1):

`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)` = `HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @varcharVariable);`

`Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input)` = `HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @nvarcharVariable);`