# Special characters in MD5 encryption

Tags: c#, sql-server, cryptography, md5, cryptographic-hash-function

I'm having a problem with MD5 encryption in C# and SQL Server, it only happens on rows with special characters.

Here is the Code in c#:

```
public virtual string RowHash<T>(T item)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var finalvalue = "";
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
        {
            if (p.Name != "Hash")
            {
                if (!p.CanWrite || !p.CanRead) { continue; }

                MethodInfo mget = p.GetGetMethod(false);
                MethodInfo mset = p.GetSetMethod(false);

                // Get and set methods have to be public
                if (mget == null) { continue; }
                if (mset == null) { continue; }
                var value = p.GetValue(item, null) == null ? "" : p.GetValue(item, null) is Entity? ((Entity)p.GetValue(item, null)).Id.ToString() : p.GetValue(item, null).ToString();
                finalvalue += value;
            }

        }
        return finalvalue;
    }

    public static string GetMD5(string text)
    {
        var md5 = MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
        var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] stream = null;

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        stream = md5.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(text));

        for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++) sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", stream[i]);

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static string PasswordMD5(string password)
    {
        var pwd = GetMD5(password + GetMD5(password).Substring(0,2));
        return pwd;
    }
```

With the method RowHash I get concatenated all the fields from the Row unless the field hash that will store the result, then I sent it to the method PasswordMD5 that creates the encrypted Hash we save in the database.

Then I do the same in SQL Server with this code:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5',CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ISNULL([Field1],''))+ISNULL([Field2],'')+ISNULL([Field3],'')+CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ISNULL([Field4],''))+ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),[Field5]),'')+ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),Field6]),'')+CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),Field7]))+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),HashBytes('MD5',CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ISNULL([Field1],''))+ISNULL([Field2],'')+ISNULL([Field3],'')+CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ISNULL([Field4],''))+ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),Field5]),'')+ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),[Field6]),'')+CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),Field7]))) 2), 1, )), 2)
```

Then I compare this with the Hash that I created in C# to check the integrity of the data I have in the database. This works perfectly fine for all the rows without special characters, but fail for all the rows that contain any special characters like é or ö.

This is an issue I faced some time ago, but the task was paused by other priorities, I don't remember exactly what solutions I already tried, I remember that I tried some solutions changing the encoding of the strings in C# but none worked.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you've crushed `nvarchar` data down to `varchar`, which yes: will break a lot of non-ASCII characters. Try using `nvarchar` throughout?

Comment: also: "Beginning with SQL Server 2016 (13.x), all algorithms other than SHA2_256, and SHA2_512 are deprecated. Older algorithms (not recommended) will continue working, but they will raise a deprecation event." - the server doesn't want you to use MD5 for this. *Your users* don't want you to use MD5 for this. And: it has required you to send unhashed passwords further than necessary. IMO you should hash *as soon as possible* - presumably immediately at the app tier - using a salted and strong (read: slow) hashing algorithm such as PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt.

Comment: var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding(); will remove non printable characters.

Comment: @jdweng it'll certainly nuke any non-ASCII characters, you're right; it should be fine with control characters, though

Comment: If you're not actually hashing passwords, rename the function. If you are actually hashing passwords, stop using MD5. Note that encryption is not the same thing as hashing (even if the hash is a cryptographic hash); using these words incorrectly can cause some confusion. You would not usually encrypt a hash. Hashing row data need not be done securely, if the hash is merely used as a way to speed up lookups or detect differences in an otherwise trusted environment, but hashing passwords has no such excuse.

Comment: `é` and `ö` aren't special characters. They are non-ASCII. Use `nvarchar` instead of `varchar` in the database. C# strings use Unicode so it doesn't have any issues with non-ASCII characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I cannot find a good solution using MD5, I moved to SHA256 and it worked using this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19214122/4890862

Answer (score -1):

I Use this Encrypt and Decrypt method for my code and i already tested with special character and its work fine for me. i will send you my code plz test this once i hope it will work you.

TableFilter Is common class file which file contains encrypt and decrypt method nothing else you can write these two method on .cs page.

```
public static string Encrypt(string toEncrypt, bool useHashing = true)
    {
        byte[] keyArray;
        byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);

        System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader settingsReader =
                                            new AppSettingsReader();
        // Get the key from config file

        string key = (string)settingsReader.GetValue("EncryptionKey",
                                                         typeof(String));
        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(key);
        //If hashing use get hashcode regards to your key
        if (useHashing)
        {
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            //Always release the resources and flush data
            // of the Cryptographic service provide. Best Practice

            hashmd5.Clear();
        }
        else
            keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        //set the secret key for the tripleDES algorithm
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        //mode of operation. there are other 4 modes.
        //We choose ECB(Electronic code Book)
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        //padding mode(if any extra byte added)

        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
        //transform the specified region of bytes array to resultArray
        byte[] resultArray =
          cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0,
          toEncryptArray.Length);
        //Release resources held by TripleDes Encryptor
        tdes.Clear();
        //Return the encrypted data into unreadable string format
        return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string cipherString, bool useHashing = true)
    {
        byte[] keyArray;
        //get the byte code of the string

        byte[] toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherString);

        System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader settingsReader =
                                            new AppSettingsReader();
        //Get your key from config file to open the lock!
        string key = (string)settingsReader.GetValue("EncryptionKey",
                                                     typeof(String));

        if (useHashing)
        {
            //if hashing was used get the hash code with regards to your key
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            //release any resource held by the MD5CryptoServiceProvider

            hashmd5.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            //if hashing was not implemented get the byte code of the key
            keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        }

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        //set the secret key for the tripleDES algorithm
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        //mode of operation. there are other 4 modes. 
        //We choose ECB(Electronic code Book)

        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        //padding mode(if any extra byte added)
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(
                             toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
        //Release resources held by TripleDes Encryptor                
        tdes.Clear();
        //return the Clear decrypted TEXT
        return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
    }
```

: For textbox string (instead of txtpassword.text put testingé123ö for Understanding))

```
login_Model.Password = TableFilter.Encrypt("testingé123ö");
```

: Web.config

---

```
    <add key="EncryptionKey" value="encyptionkeyvalue"/>
```